# How effective is spraying disinfectant on streets?

Tags: virology

I always wondered how effective spaying disinfectant onto outdoor ground is.

[image: Disinfectant being sprayed in Taiwan]

Source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%E8%94%A1%E7%B8%BD%E7%B5%B1%E8%A6%96%E5%B0%8E33%E5%8C%96%E5%AD%B8%E5%85%B5%E7%BE%A4_02.jpg)

I understand that viruses and bacteria will sink down to the ground. I further understand that pedestrians may transport it across the area via their shoes, which shall be prevented.

- Is the outdoor concentration of virus/bacteria particles really that high, that it helps to approach them with disinfectant?
- Wouldn't it dilute too quickly?
- Will the disinfectant droplets effectively touch the particles to inactivate them?

To me this looks more like this done to show "something" is done.

Comment: SE Biology is a question and answer site — not a discussion site or a site for floating ideas. It is concerned with the mechanisms of biological processes, not medical or social aspects of biology. For one of these reasons I think  that your question on the coronavirus outbreak is off-topic here. Question of a medical nature might be on-topic at SE Medical Sciences. Otherwise you are advised to consult more appropriate reputable sources for such information, some of which are listed [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses/4036#4036).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll look into that. Though, of course, the SARS-CoV-2 outbreak pushed me to write this today, I wondered about this in the past too. And I don't want to discuss, I seek answers, so I thought my Q's nicely fit the Q&A scheme.